# Books/Videos for the Caro-Kann

Tags: opening, caro-kann

I just started playing the Caro-Kann recently and have seen a variety of moves on white's third move.  Are there any good "all-in-one" resources to examine the different variations?  I consider the opening to be the weakest part of my game and want to strengthen is as much as I can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*The Caro-Kann: Move by Move*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857446879) is a good resource for the Caro-Kann. The repertoire covered has winning chances but is very solid. (Just make sure your rating is at least 1500; below that, learning opening is not ideal.)

Comment: Cyrus Lakdawala is a very good author. I like this book, and his book on the Slav too!

Answer (score 5):

I'm rated about 2000 USCF and have been a Caro Kann player for 10ish years.  I really loved both Peter Wells 'Grandmaster Secrets: The Caro Kann' and Joe Gallagher's 'Starting Out: The Caro Kann'.  Both provide really superior explanation along with the moves.  I don't think that you want to dive into Schandorff as a first time Caro Kann player.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another high-level book - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Play-Caro-Kann-Complete-Repertoire-Everyman/dp/1857444345

Answer (score 3):

Jovanka Houska's new book "Opening Repertoire: the Caro-Kann" is also very good, but like Schandorff's book, Houska's book is mainly aimed at a fairly high level (2000+ elo).

For an introduction to the Caro-Kann, it's hard to beat Lakdawala book recommended above, "The Caro-Kann Move by Move."  It's got enough theory to get up and running, and it's in a complete game format which is a very good way to start learning an opening.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a high-level book, then the "Grandmaster Repertoire" series can be recommended. There is one about the Caro-Kann, written by GM [Schandorff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906552568) in 2010.

It should added that, for the same series, in 2014 GM [Negi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1906552061) wrote a book on a 1.e4 repertoire for white, covering the Caro-Kann.